# Any suggestion on question title?

Tags: support, title

This is my question:

[How to use php on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596278/how-to-use-php-on-a-website)

I tried to change the title to something like "how does php work with html and js" but that's not good enough, right?

Can anyone help me summarize up a nice looking title so that the big guys can help me?

Comment: I feel so bad right now..when you ask someone a math question, aren't you say "can you help me with math?" right ?, and then tell him your question. But whats wrong with stackoverflow, do I have to say "can you help me with Homological conjectures in commutative algebra?"

Comment: What you really need is to sit down and read a beginner's book on PHP.I have no suggestions, as PHP is a corrupt language wielded by only the most evil of satan's little wizards.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't your title. If the question really deserves it, other users can edit the title. The reason why you get so many downvotes is because your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow expects questions with a clearly defined scope; other, less active Stack Exchange sites might impose less restrictions on questions.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Note that this is part of the help center of *every* Stack Exchange site, so don't expect a question like *can you help me with homological conjectures in commutative algebra?* to be well received on Mathematics Stack Exchange.